# How to using form submit method="get" in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
$action = "index.php?option=com_test&id=".$id;
?>
<form action="<?php echo $action ?>" method="get">
<input type="text" name="id" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit form is url is "`index.php&id=...`" => error can't find component

How to fix it is result "`index.php?option=com_test&id=...`"

Comment: Can you put the actual error message up — usually in Joomla they will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @Hai Truong Info Tech see my answer, I hope it helps! Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JROUTE what is it?**

In your `forum action`, you should use the functionality from [JRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) (The Component Router) to correctly route your URL in the framework to the component. `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_test&id=".$id');`.

**Why?**

To avoid problems when a menu item is created via [Menu Manager](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/65/223/), your code will be incompatible (i.e. the error `no component can be found` will be displayed).

**Incompatible? what on earth do you mean?**

This would be because someone might of created a menu item `index.php/myMenuItem/` which by joomla standards makes the default url `?option=com_test` incompatible.

> **How is Alias used in a URL?**
>
> For a menu item, Joomla! uses the alias as the URL plug. Assume that you use the first two SEF URL options and you create a menu item called Products. Your URL would be example.com/products.
>
> Joomla! also uses the primary key values of data within the URL to help the router navigate to the correct page. Continuing with the previous example, if your products menu item was for an Article­/Category Blog, the link for the Article Title and/or Read More link would have three parts:
>
> - The menu item URL - example.com/products;
> - Plus, the primary key for the Category and the Category alias - 32-fruit;
> - Plus, the primary key for the Article and the Article alias - 1-apple;
>     The complete URL is: http://example.com/products/32-fruit/1-apple

Credit ([JRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs), 2011)

**Implementation**

```
<?php
$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
$action = "index.php?option=com_test&id=".$id; ?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_($action); ?>" method="get">
<input type="text" name="id" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**Other Examples..**

If you want to see how JRoute is implemented in other components a good place to look is in the views section on the administrator component `com_menus`. In the directory `com_menus/views/items/tmpl/edit.php`.